# Is there a case in which PSD matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfy the condition $A \approx B$ but $A^2 \not \approx B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

For two PSD matrices $A, B$ and a positive number $\alpha$, let's define $A \approx_{\alpha} B$ as $A \preceq \alpha B$ and $B \preceq \alpha A$, where $A \preceq B$ means $B - A$ is PSD. And if there exists a very small $\gamma$, such that $A \approx_{1 + \gamma} B$, we say $A \approx B$.

A professor told me that if $A \approx_{1 + \epsilon} B$ for a small enough $\epsilon$, then we have $A^2 \approx_{1 + O(\epsilon \kappa)^2} B^2$, where $\kappa$ is the condition number of $A$. If this bound is tight, then it means there exists a case such that $A \approx  B$ but $A^2 \not \approx B^2$ when $\kappa(A)$ is very large.

These are my questions:

1. Is the bound of the spectral approximation error of $A^2$ and $B^2$ tight? If it is tight, how to construct an example where $A \approx  B$ but $A^2 \not \approx B^2$? If it is not, what would be a tighter bound, and how to derive it?
2. Is there a sufficient/necessary condition to make $A \approx  B$ but $A^2 \not \approx B^2$?

Comment: For $A \approx B$ and $A^2 \not\approx B^2$, Is using same $\epsilon$ for both these conditions OK ? If so, wont $B = (1+\epsilon) A$ work ? since $A \approx_{1+\epsilon} B$ and $A^2 \not\approx_{1+\epsilon} B^2$ on the other hand $A^2 \approx_{(1+\epsilon)^2} B^2$.

Comment: @Balajisb well if $\epsilon$ is small, then $(1+\epsilon)^2$ is also closed to $1$. I'm trying to find a case where you can not find a very small value $\gamma$, such that $A^2 \not \approx_{1+\gamma} B^2$. The statement of this part in the question might be somewhat misleading and I have made a modification.

Comment: I don’t know whether the bound in question is tight or not, but the best constant for the pair $(A^2,B^2)$ is definitely unbounded above. That is, for any $\epsilon>0$ and $K>0$, there always exist some positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A\approx_{1+\epsilon}B$ and $\inf\{\alpha>0:A^2\preceq\alpha B^2,\,B^2\preceq\alpha A^2\}\ge K$.

Comment: Professor? Teaching which course?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo randomized numerical linear algebra